# Nested foreach from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

```
    TitleTable         TextTable
-------------------  ---------------
Id(int)               Id (int)
Title(string)         TitleTableId (int)
                      Text (string)
                      TitleOfText(int)
```

So here is what I try to do:
I have 1 table that holds a title (titletable) and one more table which holds Text(text table), So one title will have several text that's why I use 2 tables.
And I can list Table 1 here is the code view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TitleTable)
  {
     @item.Title
  }
```

And not I need another foreach to bring text of the titles I tried this ;

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.TitleTable)
    {
      @item.Title

        foreach (var itemDesc in Model.Text.OrderBy(o => o.Id).Where(o => o.Id == item.Id))
         {
             @itemDesc.Text
         }
     }
```

and this returns null because I dont give any Id to return it only takes it from view model not from the controller so how can I reach the text and it should look like this at the end ;

```
Title 1
                                   Text 1of title 1
                                   Text 2of title 1
title 2                         
                                   text 1 of title2
                                   text 2 of title2
   @foreach (var item in Model.TitleTable)
   {
      @item.Title

     foreach (var itemDesc in Model.Text.Where(o => o.TitleTable== item.Id))
      {
       @itemDesc.Text
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make sense to me:

```
.Where(o => o.Id == item.Id)
```

You're matching the `TitleTable.Id` value with the `TextTable.Id` value?  Perhaps you meant this instead:

```
.Where(o => o.TitleTableId == item.Id)
```

Assuming `TextTable.TextTableId` is the foreign key to `TitleTable.Id` then that would be the value you'd compare to filter that collection.

Comment: item.ıd = means titletableid which I try to get from first foreach which has item  in model.titletable

Comment: @Jackal: I just tried switching it around, see if that works.  But the answer is still the same.  Your naming scheme makes it a bit difficult to follow, but the point is that you need to match on the foreign key.  Your code is comparing `Id` with `Id`, but you need to compare `Id` with `TitleTableId`.

Comment: yes you are right it should be titletableID == item.Id but how can I get foreing key in viewmodel ?

Comment: @Jackal: Well, what is `Model.Text`?  I'm assuming it's a collection of `TextTable` elements.  If it's something else, you need to specify.

Comment: its viewmodel which has Id , text, TitleID and I tried to get it from controller but still null I will edit the question

Comment: @Jackal: Then perhaps you want to compare the `TitleID` property.  We can only guess.  Your code is building these models, you know which properties mean what.

Comment: I think it works now but I get this There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. error